# Build a Python Dictionary from a Text File

Tags: python, dictionary, text, twitter

I have a text file with key words. It looks lie this:

```
tomCruise
Tom Cruise
Los Angeles, CA
http://www.tomcruise.com
Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys! 
Visit us at Facebook!
ENDBIO
katieH
NicoleKidman
END
PerezHilton
Perez Hilton
Hollywood, California
http://www.PerezH...
Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous websites
in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!
ENDBIO
tomCruise
katieH
NicoleKidman
END
```

I would like to build a dictionary from of the following format from the text file.

```py
[
  'tomCruise':{
  'name': 'Tom Cruise',
  'bio': 'Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys!\nVisit us at Facebook!',
  'location': 'Los Angeles, CA',
  'web': 'http://www.tomcruise.com',
  'following': ['katieH', 'NicoleKidman'],
},
  'PerezHilton':{
  'name': 'Perez Hilton',
  'bio': 'Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous websites in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!',
  'location': 'Hollywood, California',
  'web': 'http://www.PerezH...',
  'following': ['tomCruise', 'katieH', 'NicoleKidman'], 
  }
]
```

The Key Words **ENDBIO** and **END** are used to show where the dictionary should stop and are not to be included in the final dictionary.

EDIT:
The best approach I have tried so far is feeding the whole text file into a list. I have then tried to loop through the list looking out for the keywords to create smaller lists which I will then use to feed the dictionary.

```py
data = open('./data.txt')
lst = data.read().splitlines()
```

I get a list(lst), that looks like this

```py
['tomCruise', 'Tom Cruise', 'Los Angeles, CA', 'http://www.tomcruise.com', 'Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys! ', 'Visit us at Facebook!', 'ENDBIO', 'katieH', 'NicoleKidman', 'END', 'PerezHilton', 'Perez Hilton', 'Hollywood, California', 'http://www.PerezH...', 'Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous websites', 'in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!', 'ENDBIO', 'tomCruise', 'katieH', 'NicoleKidman', 'END', 'katieH', 'Katie Holmes', '', 'www.tomkat.com', 'ENDBIO', 'END']
```

I would now like to create the dictionary described above using this list. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Try yourself; ask if you get stuck :-)

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: @Nishant
I have added an edit with the solutions I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
import json

#with open('sample.txt','r') as f:
#    s=f.read()

s='''tomCruise
Tom Cruise
Los Angeles, CA
http://www.tomcruise.com
STARTBIO
Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys! 
Visit us at Facebook!
ENDBIO
katieH
NicoleKidman
END
PerezHilton
Perez Hilton
Hollywood, California
http://www.PerezH...
STARTBIO
Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous websites
in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!
ENDBIO
tomCruise
katieH
NicoleKidman
END'''

ls=s.split('END\n')
res=[]
outter={}

for i in range(len(ls)):
    inner={}
    bio=''
    follower=''
    var=ls[i].split('\n')
    name=var[1]
    loc=var[2]
    web=var[3].replace("STARTBIO",'')
    for k in range(len(var)):
        if "STARTBIO" in var[k]:
            bio ='\n'.join(var[k:]).split('\nENDBIO')[0].replace("STARTBIO\n","")
        if "ENDBIO" in var[k]:
            follower='\n'.join(var[k:]).split('\nEND')[0].replace("ENDBIO\n","").split('\n')
    inner['name']=name
    inner['bio']=bio
    inner['location']=loc
    inner['web']=web
    inner['following']=follower
    name=var[0]
    outter[name]=inner
    
print(json.dumps(outter, indent=4))
```

Note: I added STARTBIO to know the lines of bio.